# how to transform this xml field into a table?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005

I got this in a XML field in sql server 2005

```
<Details>
  <Attribute Type="org">6800</Attribute>
  <Attribute Type="fac">100</Attribute>
  <Attribute Type="fac">200</Attribute>
</Details>
```

what would be the syntax to transform this into a table, like this

```
 col_Type col_value
    org      6800
    fac      100
    fac      200
```

I'm currently stuck with singleton error while writing my query

Comment: How are you trying to accomplish this transformation? Can you post your current code and point out the problems and failures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found how to do it

if someone want to know how:

```
    declare @XmlContent xml

    set @XmlContent = '<Details>
      <Attribute Type="org">6800</Attribute>
      <Attribute Type="fac">100</Attribute>
      <Attribute Type="fac">200</Attribute>
    </Details>'

    SELECT
             Details.Attribute.value('(@Type)[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS 'Type',
             Details.Attribute.value('(.)[1]', 'int') AS 'Value'
          FROM
             @XmlContent.nodes('/Details/Attribute') AS Details(Attribute)
```